# Can I revert 'Color Sketch' mode on a Nikon camera?

Tags: effect, special-effects

I've just taken a bunch of photos without realising that my Nikon D5200 camera's 'color sketch' mode was enabled. Is there any way to revert them to real, effect-free photos?

Comment: If JPEG is all you've got, converting to black and white might relieve the effect somewhat - not completely undoing, but at least somewhat hiding the processing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Effects are almost all irreversible. This is because the vast majority of them remove details, gradations and color. *Sketch* look removes color-variations as do most types of painterly, pop art, etc effects, depending on the camera. Even something like the *miniature* effect blurs details out of most of the image which makes them unrecoverable.

Now as @Philip said, if you have a RAW file, then the effect is not applied on your data, only shown as processing. This lets you reset and do your own processing to produce a more natural looking image.

Answer (score 5):

Where you shooting in RAW or RAW+JPEG mode? (assuming you can even shoot RAW with the effects mode enabled). If so, then it will just be a matter of re-processing the RAW file. If not, the answer is almost certainly "no" - it may be possible to "undo" some of the effect via Photoshop or your other favourite image editor, but it's almost certainly more trouble than it's worth unless these were *really* valuable photos.